# ubuntu20.04: traversing the folders very slow using File Manager

Tags: filemanager

Ubuntu: 20.04
Laptop: asus zephyrus M(dual boot, i7-9750h, 1660ti, 8gb ram)

Accessing the File Manager from the Files icon in the Ubuntu Activities panel:

- No problem in launching the "Files" on clicking in Activities panel.
  But afterwards selecting & opening the folders is very slow, After clicking a
  folder to open, it is taking more than 10 second to open & load the
  contents of folder.

Comment: I installed another file manager "dolphin"& it is working smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue turns out having my VM's paused were still hogging resources. After I shut down the VM everything when back to normal.